# Is there a function to do two things at same on js?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm trying to change this js script to work as follow: I need to hide another section and the same button at the same time is shown the already working section.

Someone can point me in the right direction? I would love to know what to put into the JS as I'm a total coding noob and can't figure myself how to solve it.

```js
function showStores() {
  var x = document.getElementById("allstores");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showStores()">See All Stores</button>

<div id="allstores">All stores</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can put more code into `showStores()`, or you can call another function: `onclick="showStores(); doSomethingElse()"`

Comment: It sounds like you need an "accordion". There are lots of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toggle the hidden

Also use the recommended addEventListener instead of inline click

```js
document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click",function() {
 
  const x = document.getElementById("allStores");
  const y = document.getElementById("someStores");
  
  x.hidden = !x.hidden
  y.hidden = !y.hidden
  this.innerText = x.hidden ? 'See all stores' : 'See some stores'
})
```

```html
<button type="button" id="toggle">See All Stores</button>

<div id="allStores" hidden>All stores</div>
<div id="someStores">Some stores</div>
```

If you do not like .hidden you can use a class

```js
document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click",function() {
 
  const x = document.getElementById("allStores");
  const y = document.getElementById("someStores");
  x.classList.toggle("hide")
  y.classList.toggle("hide")
  this.innerText = x.classList.contains("hide") ? 'See all stores' : 'See some stores'
})
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="toggle">See All Stores</button>

<div id="allStores" class="hide">All stores</div>
<div id="someStores">Some stores</div>
```

Comment: This is the best answer but im trying to figure out how to do it with elementor as there it seems that "Div ID Hidden" is impossible to develop this way.

Comment: Your code seems to match this https://youtu.be/simB8W7KVAs?t=346

Comment: I added an example using a class